# How to show images with equal size in a Viewbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, wpf-controls

I have the following code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Viewbox Height="100" >

        <Canvas x:Name="pluginTile" Style="{StaticResource productImageTopFade}" Width="320" Height="200">
            <Image Panel.ZIndex="1" Source="{Binding PluginImagePath}" Margin="0,10,15,0"  ></Image>
            <Canvas.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Opacity="0.15" Direction="270" BlurRadius="20" />
            </Canvas.Effect>
         </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
    <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
        <Label FontWeight="Normal" Name="ProductName"  Content="{Binding NameAndEdition}" Margin="0 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Gray"   />
    </Border></StackPanel>
```

I have images with different dimensions which I want to show in the viewbox, the code mentioned above is part of a ItemContainerStyle of a ListBox.
The problem is I am getting images with different sizes in the listbox, some of them are getting cut while some shrink in size, is there any way that i can show these images with the same size?

Comment: [ViewBox.Stretch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx)? You have to [read](https://blog.udemy.com/wpf-viewbox/) about how `ViewBox` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Grid panel instead of a canvas and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `Stretch="FiLL"` property to your Image.

Comment: i have tried it, by setting that property it starts overlapping with the text of the label outside the viewbox. dont know why

Comment: @Sameed Can we see a small print screen of what you mean?